# Get with regex everything within a table (html)

Tags: regex

```
"<td style="text-align: center; background-color: #20c41d"><a href="http://bugbuster.fronius.com:8080/job/Platforms/job/Coyote/job/ExecutedTests/job/DM-HM-Coyote%20UpdateHelper/581/">581</a></td>"
```

Hello, can someone help me with a regex for this table.

What I want is to get every content within it, so for example in this code up i want 0, Testing123, 0, 0, No Results

I tried it with

```
<td>(.*?)<\/td>
```

which only gives me all within the exact phrase td - is there a way to make the regex so I get everything even if there is a <a href or anything else between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
<([^\/<> ]+)(?: [^<>]*)?>([^<>]+)<\/\1>
```

`<` *Group#1(*something with no "/<> "*)* space? some argument `>` *Group#2(*data*)* `</` match *group#1* `>`

Capture group #1 contain a, td, span or any other tag

Capture group #2 contain the data you want

With your data,
group #1 match :

```
a
td
span
span
span
```

and group #2 match :

```
0
Testing123
0
0
No Results
```

Comment: Found a small problem - on this string it doesnt find the 581 : <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #20c41d"><a href="http://bugbuster.fronius.com:8080/job/Platforms/job/Coyote/job/ExecutedTests/job/DM-HM-Coyote%20UpdateHelper/581/">581</a></td>

Comment: edited the full text into the question, does not work with the advanced regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235385/discussion-between-patate1684-and-dominik-lemberger).

Comment: I have updated my answers again with a more robust regex that should work better with other cases know.